# King of Tokyo: Background Dweller

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Background Dweller states the following:

> You can always reroll any [3] you have.

Can you reroll the 3's only after you are done rerolling or also inbetween?

Answer (score 8):

At any time, including between other rolls, and these do not count against your normal reroll count.